# PDO : managing sql errors

Tags: php, mysql, mobile, pdo, unique-constraint

I'm building an mobile app that connect to a server.

My SQL query insert data as email and password, with a UNIQUE constraint on email. It is called from my app with a post and return the PDO output (the trace of the exception if any).

I want to display the user if he enter an email already registered.

For now, I can think of 2 things :

- either I test before the query if email is in the database
- or I test after the query if `$pdo_exception->getCode()` equals `23000`, [which seems to be the code for UNIQUE duplicates keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key)

The first solution means another call to the database, which is not really wanted, and the second doesn't seem to be made for this, since I didn't find anything on the web.

> **What is the actual best way ?**

(the same question could go for any other exception)

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion and circumstances... both options are valid, you need to weigh the factors in your case.

Comment: Is that error code sufficient to detect duplicate emails? Might another column trigger a false positive? How much traffic do you anticipate getting? How expensive is it to do two queries. And so on...

Comment: Unless you lock the table race conditions might result in an ER_DUP_KEY anyway. And yes, any unique constraint can trigger that error.